# Another Multipart Identifier Could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

There are a million of these questions; I have *just* started working with SQL and I can't seem to drag an answer out of them. I don't understand the context well enough; promise I'll keep this simple.

```
USE [Metrics]
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitString)
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstringcomma(dbo.tblRawData.DelimitedString)
```

I get a "Multipart identifer could not be bound" for the `dbo.tblrawdata.DelimitedString` portion of the query.

I've checked spelling (I used the IDE suggestions to insert the names, so I think it's good) and I've actually gotten the statement to work in the following format:

```
USE [Metrics]
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitString)
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstringcomma('1,2,3,4,5')
```

Often the "FROM" statement is identified as being the problem (not identifying all tables that will be involved) but I'm not sure that I know how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DelimitedString` data is stored in the table `dbo.tblRawData` then you need to select from the table and then apply that `delimitedString` column to the split string function. It seems like you want the following:

```
USE [Metrics]
INSERT INTO dbo.tblSplitData(SplitString)
SELECT c.* 
FROM dbo.tblRawData d -- your table
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstringcomma(d.DelimitedString) c  -- function that you pass
                                                       -- in the delimited string
```

Comment: Well there certainly is no shallow end when it comes to TSQL! Can I ask what the "c.*" is? Does TSQL assign aliases at the end of the line? 'dbo.splitstringcomma(d.DelimitedString) c'

Comment: @Chris the `c` is the alias for the `dbo.splitstringcomma` udf. The `c.*` will return only the values from the split string udf.